# Why do we refer to car manufacturer as 'Make'?

Tags: etymology, reason-why

When I first encountered it years ago, I was pretty sure it must be a mistake. Although I got used to it, it still *does not feel right*.

What is the reason for that? Is it something specific to the automobile industry? Are there (maybe) historical reasons for it?

Comment: It seems like a rational derivation of maker: a person or thing that makes or produces something.

Comment: Its an exact, 100%, synonym for "brand" or "marque". No mystery whatsoever.  (Often when learning another language, a word will 'feel' strange, because of, the order you learned other words in.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Make* as in *car make* is not a recent innovation derived from the verb, as one is tempted to believe, but is based on the definition "the manner in which a thing is made". The OED's earliest attestation for this use of *make* is dated 1375.

Answer (score 10):

No, the term *make* as a noun is not unique to automotive industry. In fact, the [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/make) says:

> the manufacturer or trade name of a product.

Even though it is often heard when speaking about cars, the word *make* can refer to any type of product. Consider:

> There are many different *makes* and models of reel, which can be used for this type of zander fishing.
>
> To be a pilot you need to know aerodynamics and a bit about the engines but you don't need to know the *make* of the fuel pump.